# Accessing information from a struct

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, struct, mkmapview

I am trying to add annotations to a map but I am having trouble accessing the different variables stored in my struct. I would like to set the name, latitude and longitude to draw off of an element in the variable restaurants. However, when trying to implement the latitude, longitude and name, I get error messages. How would I do this so that I can access any restaurant's name, latitude and longitude inside of my variable.

Here is my code.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

struct PlacesOnMap {
var name: String
var latitude: Double
var longitude: Double

init(name: String, latitude: Double, longitude: Double) {
    self.name = name
    self.latitude = latitude
    self.longitude = longitude
}
}

class MapViewController: UIViewController {

var restaurants = [PlacesOnMap(name: "Pete's", latitude: -73.2455, longitude: 65.4443),
    PlacesOnMap(name: "Bake shop on 5th", latitude: 34.55555, longitude: 34.3333),
    PlacesOnMap(name: "Italian", latitude: -33.4444, longitude: 43.567)
]


@IBOutlet var mapView: MKMapView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}


func setRestaurantsAnnotations() {
    let places = MKPointAnnotation()
    places.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: restaurants.latitude, longitude: restaurants.longitude) //I get the error: Value of type '[PlacesOnMap]' has no member 'latitude' or 'longitude'
    places.title = restaurants.name //I get the error: Value of type '[PlacesOnMap]' has no member 'name'
    mapView.addAnnotation(places)
}
}
```

Comment: `restaurants`  is an array containing three places. Which one did you want the name of? The Swift compiler can’t guess, and neither can I actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this is what you want to do:

```
restaurants.forEach { placeOnMap in
    let place = MKPointAnnotation()
    place.coordinate =  CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: placeOnMap.latitude, longitude: placeOnMap.longitude)
    place.title = placeOnMap.name
    mapView.addAnnotation(place)
}
```

As mentioned by @matt in the comments section, restaurant is an array of `PlacesOnMap`. Your goal is to add these places to the map, so you need to convert each of these places to a `CLLocationCoordinate2D` instance and then add it to your map.

Alternatively, you can do it this way:

```
let places = restaurants.map { placeOnMap -> MKPointAnnotation in
    let place = MKPointAnnotation()
    place.coordinate =  CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: placeOnMap.latitude, longitude: placeOnMap.longitude)
    place.title = placeOnMap.name
    return place
}
mapView.addAnnotations(places)
```

In this one, you're mapping the array of restaurants that you have into an array of `MKPointAnnotation` instances and then you just pass this array to the `mapView`.